How to process two very large JSON files with Python?
I have two files named smaller_file.json and larger_file.json. While both have the potential to be quite large, reaching over 200MB, the smaller_file.json will always be the smaller of the two.
I want to loop through the smaller file, pick out the name values for each JSON object, and then check if any of these names are found in the larger file.
I'm aiming to make this process as quick as possible while also being memory-efficient by avoiding the need to load both files entirely into memory.
What do you think is best approach to do this?

Write parser function in Rust. And then call it from python.

Does this answer your question? Is there a memory efficient and fast way to load big JSON files?

Where I've had to solve this problem, I parsed the XML incrementally and then inserted it into a SQLite database. I was then able to search using SQLite. If your XML is very structured, you can set up appropriate tables. If it is deeply nested and complex, perhaps use https://www.ibase.ru/files/articles/programming/dbmstrees/sqltrees.html as a strategy for representing the tree. But the idea remains the same.

The most time efficient way will always be to load them into memory:
import json

with open('small.json') as f:
    dict = json.load(f)

and then work with them as a python dictionary.
If you are committed to not loading them entirely into memory, you can use the ijson library with ijson.items() which creates a generator:
# put the names from the small json into a set
names = set()    
with open('small_file.json', 'r') as f:
    objects = ijson.items(f, 'item')
    for obj in objects:
        if 'name' in obj:
            names.add(obj['name'])

# all the names from the small file
print(names)

# check if the names are in the large json and print them
with open('large_file.json', 'r') as f:
    objects = ijson.items(f, 'item')
    for obj in objects:
        if 'name' in obj and obj['name'] in names:
            print(f"name found in large json: {obj['name']}")

